# Disable all notifications from Exchange calendar

Tags: notifications, calendar, google-calendar

I'm using a Nexus 5X, running Android 7.1.2 and using Google Calendar 5.7.20.

I want to view my work calendar on my phone, so I can see it when planning personal things, but don't want notifications, as I have a separate phone (and laptop) for work which go "ding" at the appropriate moment.

In Google Calendar settings, under that account I have set the "Default notifications" to be "No notification", but I still get notifications.

I think it might be due to notifications set within each event (These are useful on my laptop, I don't want to turn them off).

Is there a way to disable the notifications for that calendar, but keep it visible along with the others?

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard notifications for each calendar in Calendar Settings. One for normal dates and a second for full-day.

You must deactivate both, otherwise you can still get some notification.